Gray out part of an image
Using a Stack which holds an Image and a layer on top of that.
The layer on top is smaller than the Image. It is supposed to gray out only a the part of the underlying image.
The idea is to move this greyscale filtering layer around. Which is why it has to sit in its own layer; the grayscale filter cannot be the direct parent of the Image.
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.asset('bla', fit: BoxFit.contain),
    Positioned( /* WILL MOVE AROUND LATER */
      top: 50,
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 50,
      child: Colors.red.withAlpha(100),  /* GRAYSCALE FILTER HERE */
    )
  ]
)


can you share the reference image.

Thanks to one comment this simplified code does create a ValueNotifier<Rect> which adds the grayed-out effect to an area of the Image.
Setting the value of ValueNotifier<Rect> is then used to move the Rect around or to change its size.
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Foo(
    image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'),
  ))));
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foo({super.key, required this.image});

  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final rect = ValueNotifier(Rect.zero);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('BUILD');

    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      // print('LAYOUT');

      final size = constraints.biggest;

      if (!constraints.biggest.isEmpty && rect.value == Rect.zero) {
        // Future(() {
        rect.value = Alignment.center.inscribe(size / 2, Offset.zero & size);
        // });
      }

      return Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image(
            image: widget.image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          ClipRect(
            clipper: FooClipper(rect: rect),
            child: Image(
              image: widget.image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.grey,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.hue,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => rect.value = Alignment.center
                          .inscribe(size / 4, Offset.zero & size),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left)),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => rect.value = Alignment.center
                          .inscribe(size / 2, Offset.zero & size),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right)),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

class FooClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  FooClipper({required this.rect}) : super(reclip: rect);

  final ValueNotifier<Rect> rect;

  @override
  ui.Rect getClip(ui.Size size) => rect.value;

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<ui.Rect> oldClipper) => true;
}

